# Replace the particular value of array by some other value using python for loop

Tags: python

```
staff_text=['31','32']
staffing_title = ['14','28','14','20']
```

I have two array like above.and i want output like

```
staffing_title = ['31','28','32','20']
```

So basically whenever 14 comes in  staffing_title array it replace by staff_text values.

ex if first 14 comes replace by 31,When second 14 comes replace by 32 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the one liner using list comprehension :

```
>>> staffing_title = ['14', '28', '14', '20']
>>> staff_text=['31','32']

>>> res = [staff_text.pop(0) if item == str(14) else item for item in staffing_title ]
>>> print(res)
['31', '28', '32', '20']
```

Comment: I want the output value inside array

Comment: I have also added one liner ( pythonic way) , @VivekSingh Please check

Answer (score 0):

The following will do it:

```
>>> [t if t != '14' else staff_text.pop() for t in staffing_title]
['32', '28', '31', '20']
```

Note that this modifies `staff_text`, so you might want to make it operate on a copy.

This code assumes that there are at least as many elements in `staff_text` as there are `'14'` strings in `staffing_title` (but then you don't specify what should happen if there aren't).